# Debugging a 2D array in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array which contains height information. I want to see it in the debugger to a certain point if the values are correct. I know we can see a 1D array using "myArray,5", but it doesn't work when i write "myArray,5,5" or "myArray[0],5", without the quotation marks.

Does anybody know how to do this? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first, you can view memory block contents at specified address (myArray).

As second you can mouseover your array, and from pop-up menu show array members.

Comment: I have not used the Memory pane before. Thanks.